# Method not running in Main

Tags: c#

I am a beginner c# programmer and i am working on a login form, but i have the problem that when the login form finishes, it doesn't run the next method in main.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recipe_Man
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        static int tries = 3;
        static bool isLoggedIn = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (!isLoggedIn)
            {
                // Login form going
                LoginForm();
            }
            // Script to run after Login
            CreateRecipe();
        }

        static void CreateRecipe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finsihed");
        }

        static void LoginForm()
        {
            Console.Write("Login or Create: ");
            string loginInput = Console.ReadLine();
            string login = loginInput.ToLower();
            if (login == "create")
            {
                Console.Write("Username: ");
                string x = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Password: ");
                string y = Console.ReadLine();

                keys.Add(x, y);

                Console.WriteLine("Please login with your new account");
                CheckAccount();
            }
            else if (login == "login")
            {
                CheckAccount();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void CheckAccount()
        {
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string y = Console.ReadLine();
            string z;

            keys.TryGetValue(x, out z);

            if (z == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username or Password isn't found");
                CheckAccount();
            }
            else if (tries == 0)
            {
                Banned();

            }
            else if (z == y)
            {
                AccessGranted(x);
            }
            else if (tries >= 0 && z != y)
            {
                tries--;
                AccessDenied();
            }
        }

        static void AccessGranted(string username)
        {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            Console.Write($"Welcome {username}, we are here to make a fantastic experince for you");
        }

        static void AccessDenied()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You have been denied you have {tries} more tries");
            CheckAccount();
        }

        static void Banned()
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

So i have tried to use a while loop, but i couldn't really figure it out. I expect it to say "Finished", after you login. Right now it just doesn't show finished, the last thing it says is the welcome message.

Comment: I found out that you have to press enter, is it possible to make it automatically run?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` does just that, it reads a line from the console.  How would it know that your entry was finished if you didn't press `[Enter]` when you finished.  Now, do note that you have an extra `Console.ReadLine` at the end of your `LoginForm` method

Comment: As Michael pointed out, the extra `Console.ReadLine();` makes it appear that `CreateRecipe();` doesn't run. In fact your code hasn't gotten there yet. Your current code is a bit convoluted. I wanted to give you something to look at that might be useful for you. Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVnM9p

Answer (score 1):

The next method will be called but there is an extra Console.ReadLine() at the end of the LoginForm method which pauses the execution waiting for user input. If you were to remove that the CreateRecipe method will be called